# Loading Network.HTTP module in Haskell on GHC7.4.1

Tags: http, haskell, module

I am trying to load a file in GHCi (Windows 7 / Haskell Platform 2012.2.0.0 ) which starts with:

```
import Network.HTTP
import System.IO
...
```

But I get an error:

```
Could not find module `Network.HTTP'
```

This module is in HTTP package, right? So when I run `>cabal list HTTP` it finds the following:

```
* HTTP
    Synopsis: A library for client-side HTTP
    Default available version: 4000.2.3
    Installed version: 4000.2.3
    Homepage: https://github.com/haskell/HTTP
    License: BSD3
```

Which means the package is installed right? What do I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure , have you restarted ghci after cabal install ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the package installed by cabal doesn't make it automatically available to your code. (For example, you could have installed 2 versions of some package, so it's not possible to determine automatically what to make available and what to hide).

Probably the simplest solution is to manage, build and run your project using cabal as well. See [How to write a Haskell program](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program), Section 2 describes (among other things) how to set up the files required by Cabal. In particular, your cabal file will contain a line similar to this:

```
build-depends: base, HTTP
```

See also [Cabal User Guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/).

---

**Edit:** You can try the following:

Create file `test.cabal` containing:

```
Name:                test
Version:             0.0
Description:         My network program
Build-Type:          Simple
Cabal-Version:       >=1.2

Executable test
  Main-is:           Test.hs
  Build-Depends:     base >= 4 && < 5, HTTP
```

(Replace `Test.hs` with your source file.) Then Run

```
cabal install --only-dependencies
```

this installs all required dependencies. If it all goes well, you can configure and build the project:

```
cabal configure
cabal build
```

---

Maybe to work interactively with your project, you could use [cabal-ghci](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-ghci). I haven't tried it, but looks like it could be just what you need.

Comment: Uh... isn't installing things by cabal pretty much supposed to make any included modules available in code? If you install another version of something, cabal hides the old version.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák, thank you for prompt response! I've had a look at the resources you gave links to, and I will try to build a package with Cabal, but for now I just want to add that I just have a .hs file and I open it with winghci.exe, and the loading fails because of the error. I guess that winghci just doesn't know about the packages installed by Cabal (particularly Network.HTTP in this case)? But what about other modules? For example, if I add `import Network.URI` to the same file, then no errors occur. Also, is there a way to tell winghci.exe about Network.HTTP existence? Thank you!

Comment: You can use `:set -package xxx-version` to make GHCi use a specific version and hide all the others. No need to create Cabal description just for that. Note that you only need it when there's more than one version installed, and you need to use an older one.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus You're right, this is even simpler. More info can be found in GHC manual [2.6.1. Packages](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-invocation.html#id551345) and also [4.9.1. Using Packages](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html#using-packages). Setting up Cabal is slightly more complicated, but once working, it makes it easier to work with the project.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, I tried doing this in a ghci window `:set -package Network.HTTP`, it responded with `"cannot satisfy -package Network.HTTP"` though. Then I added -v to it, and it returned an explanation, saying `"package HTTP-4000.2.3-... is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies: network-2.3.0.13-... parsec-3.1.2-..."`. I checked my installed version, and it turned out that I have network-2.3.0.14 and parsec-3.1.3. I did `:set -package parsec-3.1.2`, it loaded, then I did `:set -package network-2.3.0.13`, but again it returned an error, saying:

Comment: `cannot satisfy -package network-2.3.0.13: 
network-2.3.0.13-..is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies: parsec-3.1.2-..`; Am I moving in a correct direction? Why doing `:set -package network-2.3.0.13` returned an error?

Comment: Seems you just need to add the _parsec_ package and it could work. (AFAIK Cabal resolves transitive dependencies, so using it could be simpler than adding them by hand, if you have a lot of them.)

Comment: @KirillG. Run `ghc-pkg check` and then reinstall all packages that are reported as broken. You'll need Cygwin to build `network`, though — Google it, there's a guide somewhere.

Comment: @PetrPudlák, thank you for extended example. Indeed this worked, and your solution could be used to resolve this particular problem.